# PopupWindow showAtLocation with editText doesn't keep her position when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a little problem with a popup window showed by the method showAtLocation .
This is my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/itemSearchMargin"
            android:text="@string/itemSearchPopup"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titleitemSearchTextSize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardviewSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popupSearchSubtitle">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/hub3_search_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSearchEditTextHeight"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/Search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/itemSearchEditTextPaddingEnd"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#FF000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hub3_search_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/itemSearchEditTextHeight"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSearchEditTextHeight"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/magnify" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hub3_cancel_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/itemSearchXSize"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/itemSearchXSize"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/hub3_search_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/close"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popupSearchSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/itemSearchMargin"
            android:text="@string/popupSearchSubtitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/itemSearchSubtitle"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bodyItemSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bodyItemSearch"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageBodyItemSearch"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardviewSearch"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageBodyItemSearch"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bodyItemSearch"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_search_item" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/groupbodyItemSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            card_view:constraint_referenced_ids="bodyItemSearch,imageBodyItemSearch" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarItemSearch"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardviewSearch"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/groupLoadingItemSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:constraint_referenced_ids="progressBarItemSearch" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/itemSearchList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/grayF4"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchFoundItemSearch"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchFoundItemSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/itemSearchSubtitle"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardviewSearch" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/searchListGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:constraint_referenced_ids="itemSearchList,searchFoundItemSearch" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I have to fix the popupwindow at some coordinates x,y, and to do that I have used this method:

popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0] , location[1])

when the recyclerview is empty and the keyboard is showed the popup windows is showed at correct position, but sadly when the recycler view is not empty and the keyboard is showed the popup windows doesn't mantein her position and it moving up

EDIT: I have used the showAtLocation, because with showAsDropDown the popupView follow the anchor view also during the ui refresh, and this leads to a rapid movement from random position to the correct one. I have tryed to resolve using the showAtLocation to a x,y coordinates.. whith your solution I suppose I will have the same problem that I encoured with showAsDropDown

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code for opening popupwindow and set anchor view to adjust position

```
private void openTeacherList() {
    ArrayAdapter specializationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, teacherNameList);
    final ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
 {
            binding.txtTeacher.setText(teacherNameList.get(position));
            teacherId = teacherList.get(position).getId() + "";
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });



 popupWindow.setContentWidth(androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(androidx.appcompat.widget.ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setAnchorView(binding.txtTeacher);
    popupWindow.setAdapter(specializationAdapter);
    popupWindow.show();
 }
```

Comment: I have used the showAtLocation, because with showAsDropDown the popupView follow the anchor view also during the ui refresh, and this leads to a rapid movement from random position to the correct one. I have tryed to resolve using the showAtLocation to a x,y coordinates.. whith your solution I suppose I will have the same problem that I encoured with showAsDropDown